# razor css file - styles are not applied

Tags: razor, blazor

This is my following code for formcommon.razor

```
<MudItem xs="12" md="3" Style="margin-top: 15px!important;margin-left: -70px!important;">
                            <MudTooltip Text="some tooltip">
                                <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Class="button-min-width"  Color="Color.Primary">?</MudButton>
                            </MudTooltip>
                        </MudItem>
```

this works perfectly as the margin-left is -70px.

but when i move these to .css files which is  formcommon.razor.css

```
.marginIn {
    margin-top: 15px!important;
    margin-left: -70px!important;
}
```

and change this formcommon.razor to

```
<MudItem xs="12" md="3" Class="marginIn">
                            <MudTooltip Text="some tooltip">
                                <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Class="button-min-width"  Color="Color.Primary">?</MudButton>
                            </MudTooltip>
                        </MudItem>
```

the output is different.the margin-left is NOT -70px.

Am i missing anything?

Comment: Have you got: `yourAppName.styles.css` linked in index.html? Does it work on "pure" html (not Muditem component)?

Comment: it does work on pure html.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Notice that you are not applying any class to your component through the normal `class` attribute. In `MudItem`, `Class` is a component attribute, not an HTML attribute.

One solution would be to wrap your `MudItem` in a `div` container:

```html
<div class="marginIn">
  <MudItem />
</div>
```